# Linked questions API call fails for frequently asked questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, api, api-v2.2, linked-questions

The [Linked Questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/linked-questions) API fails for some of the [Frequently Asked Questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Frequent), maybe because of the sheer amount of linked questions they have.

As an example, take [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/4751173). Opening https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/218384/linked?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow in a browser gives

```json
{
  "error_id": 500,
  "error_message": "this error has been logged",
  "error_name": "internal_error"
}
```